# MonadPlus instance for Control.Eff when Exc is member

Tags: haskell, monadplus, effect-systems

In [monad transformers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html#t:ExceptT), we have

```
instance (Monad m, Monoid e) => MonadPlus (ExceptT e m)
```

In [extensible effects](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extensible-effects-1.7.1/docs/Control-Eff-Exception.html), there is no such thing as

```
instance (Monoid e) => MonadPlus (Eff (Exc e :> r))
```

I've tried implementing it, in vain. Here is what I have so far:

```
instance (Monoid e) => MonadPlus (Eff (Exc e :> r)) where
  mzero = throwExc mempty
  a `mplus` b = undefined $ do
                  resultA <- runExc a
                  case resultA of
                    Left l -> runExc b
                    Right r -> return $ Right r
```

There are 2 issues:

- for `mzero`, GHC complains as follows:

  ```
  Could not deduce (Monoid e0) arising from a use of ‘mempty’
    from the context (Monad (Eff (Exc e :> r)), Monoid e)
  ```

  Why doesn't GHC match `e0` with `e` ?

  **Answer** (provided in comment): turn on `ScopedTypeVariables`
- for `mplus`, `undefined` should be replaced with the inverse function of `runExc`, but I can't find it in the API of extensible-effects. Did I miss something ?

**Rationale**: I want to be able to write `a <|> b` within `Member (Exc e) r => Eff r a`, meaning:

- try `a`
- if `a` throws `ea`, try `b`
- if `b` throws `eb`, then throw `mappend ea eb`

This requires an `Alternative` instance, which is why I am attempting to implement a `MonadPlus` instance in the first place.

Note: I'm using GHC 7.8.3 .

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: "Why doesn't GHC match e0 with e" - turn on `ScopedTypeVariables`.

Comment: @user2407038 It solves the first issue indeed, thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may be confused about extensible effects and the desired
instance `MonadPlus (Eff (Exc e :> r))` shows the confusion.

If you wish to build a non-deterministic computation and also throw
exceptions, you can do that already without any need for new
instances. I think I may be partly responsible for the confusion by
defining separate mzero' and mplus' which are fully equivalent to
those in MonadPlus. Anyway, because of this equivalence, 
you can simply write

```
instance Member Choose r => MonadPlus (Eff r) where
    mzero = mzero'
    mplus = mplus'
```

The instance says: A computation that has a Choose effect, among
others, is an instance of the MonadPlus computation. Let me stress
the part ``among others''. The computation may have other effects,
for example, throw exceptions. The MonadPlus instance above covers
that case, as well as all others.

Thus, to use non-determinism and exceptions, you just use mplus, mzero
(or mplus', mzero') along with throwExc. There is no need to define
any new instances - in stark contrast with Monad Transformers.

Of course you have to decide how you want your exceptions to interact
with non-determinism: should an exception discard all choices or only
remaining choices? This depends on how you order your handlers, which
effect gets handled first. Moreover, you can write a handler for both
Choose and Exc effects (to keep the already made choices upon an
exception and discard the remaining -- thus modeling Prolog's cut).
The code of the library (and the code accompanying the paper) has examples of that.

**Edit in reply to the amended question:**
If all you need is `<|>`, it can be implemented simply, without MonadPlus or cut.
This operator is merely a form of exception handling, and is implementable as the
composition of two catchError. Here is the full code

```
alttry :: forall e r a. (Typeable e, Monoid e, MemberU2 Exc (Exc e) r) =>
          Eff r a -> Eff r a -> Eff r a
alttry ma mb =
  catchError ma $ \ea ->
  catchError mb $ \eb -> throwError (mappend (ea::e) eb)
```

If the computation ma finishes successfully, its result is returned. Otherwise,
mb is tried; it it finishes successfully, its result is returned. If both fail,
the mappend-ed exception is raised. The code directly matches the English specification.

We use MemberU2 in the signature rather than Member to
ensure that the computation throws only one type of exceptions.
Otherwise, this construction is not very useful. I used the original implementation 
[Eff.hs](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/extensible/Eff.hs). That file also contains the test case.

BTW, with extensible effects there is no
need to define or use type classes like MonadPlus, MonadState, etc. These type classes
were intended to hide the concrete layout of the MonadTransformer stack. With extensible effects, there is nothing to hide. The crutches are no longer needed.

Comment: OK, I need a little more reading and testing to understand Control.Eff.Cut. In the meantime, I've updated the question with my underlying goal which is to leverage the `<|>` operator from `Alternative`. Will Prolog's cut model help me do that ?

Comment: Regarding "there is no need to define or use type classes like MonadPlus, MonadState": I understand `Eff r a` already hides the concrete elements of the underlying union type `r`, however I'm still interested in using `Monad`* type classes for name overloading purposes. `a <|> b` looks better than `a \`alttry\` b`, don't you think ? Anyway, thank you for the detailed answer, it helps a lot.